# Как сделать верный запрос в базу данных?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Есть таблица.

```
id |  parent | city
--------------------
1  |   null   | 1
2  |   1      | null
3  |   1      | 1
4  |   1      | 2
5  |   null   | null
```

Как в laravel сделать запрос, чтобы получить все записи, где parent = 1, а city равен 1 или null 
В данном случае - это записи с id 2 и 3.

Пробовал так:

```
DB::table('table')->where('parent ', '=', 1)->where('city', '=', 1)->orwhereNull('city')->get();
```

Возвращает все записи, где city null

Как вариант вижу - сделать два отдельных запроса, а потом их объединить, но хотелось-бы в один впихнуть...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$someVar = 1;
DB::table('table')->where('parent ', 1)->where(function($query) use ($someVar){
    $query->where('city', 1)
    ->orWhereNull('city');
})->get();
```

Comment: А как в function($query){ передать переменную ?

Comment: поправил.......